# Find largest digit in decimal number

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a C function  which will ask the user to enter in a number (44634329)  and will `scanf` the number, save it to a variable , and will go through digit by digit, and figure out the largest number.

http://pastebin.com/tF7PVtvg - this is my project so far

```
void extractLargestDigit() {

int i;
i = 0;
int v;
v = 0;
int x;
x = 0;

printf("Enter an integer : ");
scanf("%d", &x);

    i = x % 10;
x = x / 10 % 10;

if(i >= x) { i = i; x = x / 10 % 10;}
if(x >= i) { i = x; x = x / 10 % 10;}
if(x = 0)  { i = i;}
```

Right here is where I'm trying to make the program loop so that it will continue to     cycle through until x is equal to 0.  I'm hoping that this will make `i` be the largest value in the number and will display it as such.  I also have to display at what point the largest digit occurs , like in the number 542356976 , the right most 6 is in the 1st digit position, and the 9 is in the 3rd digit position, I need to display where the largest digit occurs in the number and have not quite figured that out

```
printf("\nThe largest digit : %d\n", i);
    printf("\nIts position : );


    return;
 }
```

Any help or insight would be awesome

Comment: I actually edited the code slightly so that V isnt used anymore, im not sure which is beter

Comment: Just a piece of advice that will help your instructor or anyone else reading your code:  giving your variables meaningful names often helps readability and reduces debugging time, as you don't have to walk through the code and figure out what each variable's purpose is. For example, by simply looking at `int x`, I have no idea what it represents. `int input` may have been a better definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in a different way:

```
void extractLargestDigit() {

    printf("Enter an integer : ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    int max  = -1; // so it will always be less than any first digit

        while (x >0){
            int digit = X %10; //grab last digit
            x = x / 10;        //throw last digit away
            if (max < digit)       //if this digit is grater than current max...
                max = digit;       //... update it!
    }

    return max;
}
```

This way, you loop through each digit in turn, and the greatest on will be in `max` varible.

Comment: @st0le Why you think that? Basically it checks if the max digit is lower than the digit that is being evaluated. If that is the case, than this digit should be the max, considering what was evaluated so far, and than max is updated. Am i wrong?

Comment: the digit being evaluated is in the variable `digit`, isnt it?

Answer (score 5):

Why does the input necessarily have to be treated as an integer? You may consider treating the input as a string instead. Then, each digit is a `char` in an array of ascii characters, making it very easy to loop through the digits.

By looking at an ascii table, you'll notice the numerical values of the ascii digits 0-9 are in ascending order, which means comparing them for which is the largest is quite easy.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to use a loop then.

```
do {
   // grab input, process...
} while( x != 0 );
```

Also...

```
if(x = 0)
```

That is an assignment, i.e., x will *always* equal zero when that executes and the `if` block will never be entered.  If you want to check equality, use `==`.

```
if(x == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop. Something like this:

```
while (x != 0)
{
  // ...

  x /= 10;
}
```

In the loop, check the current last digit (which is `x % 10`), and track the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
while(x>0)
{
     i=x%10;
     x/=10;
     // here check to see if 'i' is the biggest so far
}
```

Also, don't use variables with single-letter names. It's easy to forget what they are. (In fact, I can't tell in your code which variable is supposed to track the largest digit found so far.)

Comment: This has helped me get through the loop so i is constantly moving down the digits, but im having trouble with the if i is > x stop and printf i and its position

Comment: Why would you compare `i` to `x`? You want to compare `i` to the largest digit you've found so far, and if it's larger, store `i` as the new largest digit.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit hard to read as it is formatted now. Try this (your professor will thank you) as I think it will help you better understand what you have to do. I have given you a hint on what you might need to do next as well.

```
void extractLargestDigit() {
   int i = 0; /* You can declare and initialise at the same time, by the way */
   int v = 0;
   int x = 0;

   printf("Enter an integer : ");
```

You want to keep doing everything between this and the end of the function until the user enters a zero. You need a loop construct; C provides a few. Read up on `do...while`, `for` and `while` loops and you will find something that meets your needs.

```
   scanf("%d", &x);

   i = x % 10;
   x = x / 10 % 10;

   if(i >= x) { 
       i = i; 
       x = x / 10 % 10;
   }
   if(x >= i) {
       i = x; 
       x = x / 10 % 10;
   }
   if(x = 0) { /* Something's not right here */ 
       i = i;
   }
}
```

Comment: this function is helping alot, the problem im running into is if i enter a number 3287401, then i comes out as 1, i understand the loop process youve made here if i is greater then or equal to x set i to i and continue the loop, if x is greater then or equal to i then set x to i and continue the loop and when x = 0  set i to i, but some numbers have 0 already inside it, so i added in the like x = x / 10 % 10; right after i = i; but still have some problems.